# How To Align Verticles in Straight Line

Tags: mesh, transforms, edges

I have this image with uneven ground. I'm struggling to even out these vertices, it should form an even ground and should look in a straight line because if I try to align it on a base plane, it looks very wrong and I see gaps etc.

I"ve tried using `G` option and then tried to move vertices but it distorts other part of the model. What are my options here?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to align vertices I can think of is to select all those you want to flatten, then scale them by `0`. For example `s > z > 0` key combination will flatten all your vertices along the global z to their centre of mass, and you can move things after that.

[image: Ico sphere before flattening][image: Base flattened along Z]

However it looks like what you have there is a point cloud, and in doing any editing of the vertices you'll get texture stretching (which may or may not be okay).

You could try using `Sculpt Mode` and the `Smooth` brush, but I'm not sure if that's the result you're looking for.

Note: If `G` to move vertices is moving other parts of the model make sure proportional editing is off (Shortcut for that is the letter `o`)